# How to disable Obfuscate in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, apk

I'm editing my build.gradle and proguard-rules.pro file but it still obfuscates my code. What is the reason? i will test it to reverse the code, but it obfuscates the code. How should i edit the code to not obfuscate it or is there a setting?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication2'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication2"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keep class com.my.package.** { *; }
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
```

i will test it to reverse the code, but it obfuscates the code. How should i edit the code to not obfuscate it or is there a setting?

Answer (score 0):

Change buildTypes > add 'release' >

minifyEnabled false

shrinkResources false

```kotlin
    buildTypes {
         debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
```

Comment: that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your config seems to be ok.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

This should be enough in order to disable obfuscation for debug build. Can you please provide more info about what are you building or what are you trying to do? How you understand that your app obfuscated? Do you trying to build apk or you are looking for sources in build folder? Btw try to clean project Build -> Clean Project and rebuild with debug build type.

Comment: I clean the code and then build it in debug format. Then I create build apk. I decompile the APK with the jadx-gui tool. When I look, I see that the code is obfuscated.

Comment: Ok let's try the following, again clear build, use gradle console (or cli) gradle tool in and execute assembleDebug https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode by doing this way you will definitely generate debug apk of your app. Btw you can Build -> Analyse  apk in order to explore your source apk right from the build folder.